# How to find the .egg-link file for a python model install via python setup.py develop when it is not in the usual location?

Tags: python

How to find the .egg-link file for a python model install via python setup.py develop when it is not in the usual location?

I can load the module from the repl and see the files it is pointing to. I should not be able to do this. I uninstalled it AFAIK.

EDIT: I was on two different machines. Thought I was using tmux through iterm but forgot I wasn't. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script which finds the `.egg-link`s that are currently on your `PATH`:

```
import os
import sys

for p in sys.path:
    if os.path.exists(p):
        for f in os.listdir(p):
            if f.endswith('.egg-link'):
                print(os.path.join(p, f))
```

It works by iterating through all `sys.path` entries.  Here's an example where I've `pip install -e .` inside my clone of `pre-commit`:

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit/venv/lib/python36.zip', '/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit/venv/lib/python3.6', '/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit/venv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit']
```

Some of those paths are bogus (such as `...python36.zip`) so we need to filter those out with `os.path.exists(...)`

After that we search through the files inside each of those directories and print out any that end with `.egg-link`

In my case:

```
$ python3 t.py
/home/asottile/workspace/pre-commit/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pre-commit.egg-link
```

Answer (score 0):

create **init**.py in your folders and save other files on folder name lib. and then you can now use

```
setup.py build egg
```

Comment: I want to *find and destroy* the egg. Something is injecting the develop path into my sys.path.